# LNK2019 error (unresolved external symbol) linking SQLite into DLL

Tags: c++, sqlite, dll, linker-errors

I'm making a C++ DLL that requires SQLite.

I have integrated the SQLite header file (sqlite3.h) and added the library in the external dependencies. I have no syntax errors, but when I try to compile the project I get the following LNK2019 ("Unresolved external symbol [XYZ] referenced from the function …") errors:

> `error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu sqlite3_close référencé dans la fonction "void __cdecl DisonnectDB(bool,struct sqlite3 *)" (?DisonnectDB@@YAX_NPEAUsqlite3@@@Z) C:\Users\Akash\Downloads\Learn Curve\Freelance\Travis\sana\Sana\Sana.obj    Sana`
>
> `error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu sqlite3_column_text référencé dans la fonction "wchar_t const * __cdecl getTableData(struct sqlite3 *)" (?getTableData@@YAPEB_WPEAUsqlite3@@@Z) C:\Users\Akash\Downloads\Learn Curve\Freelance\Travis\sana\Sana\Sana.obj    Sana`

I have tried to do the same procedure in a test console application and I was able to compile with no errors so I am confident that the issue is not with the visibility of either the SQLite library or header file.

Other questions on Stack Overflow are not specific to how DLLs interact with static libraries.

Is there any additional configuration necessary to use the SQLite library in a DLL as opposed to the use in a console application?
How can I fix the compile time LNK2019 error?

Comment: Please translate the error messages to English.

Comment: It says 'Unresolved external symbol `sqlite3_close` referenced from the function (...)'

Comment: I rewrote the title to clarify a bit and include the error summary, as well as removing a tag from it. In the question body I included the translation of the error message (from comments) and fixed some grammar, then removed a plea for help (which is implied anyway) and fixed up a bit of formatting. Finally, another tag presented itself, so that went in too.

Comment: Sorry about the french error message, basically @NathanTuggy correction is true. The error message is an unresolved external symbol error on the library functions: sqlite3_close and sqlite3_column_text refrenced respectively in my dll functions DisconnectDB() and getTableData() .. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After extensive testing i finally found the reson for the issue. The LNK2019 error can be caused by a static library that is of a diffrent architecture than the compiling dll.

I was compiling the dll in x64 while sqlite .lib file was x86.

After compiling with the right architectures i no longer have the linker-error.

Comment: What exatly did you change to compile the dll in x86 ?

Comment: In visual studio Build > Configuration manager then choose build architecture. Sorry it took a while .. for further info check out this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx)